# How do you print the result of a PostgreSQL query in CSV or TSV format from the command line?

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to execute a query from the shell (not in the interactive psql client) and have it print the CSV or TSV representation of the output to STDOUT. How do you do that with `psql` or one of the PostgreSQL command-line tools?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

If you are using PostgreSQL 8.2 or newer, use this for CSV:

```
psql -c "COPY (<select query>) TO STDOUT WITH CSV"
```

and this of TSV, with proper NULLs:

```
psql -c "COPY (<select query>) TO STDOUT WITH NULL AS ''"
```

The CSV form will properly quote any fields that contain the double-quote character.  See the PostgreSQL documentation of your specific version for more details and options for COPY.

Comment: It really does make this stuff easy, don't it? Imagine the answer from some of the "big database vendors"...  First install this 64 Meg package and then run this export tool that has the most arcane syntax imaginable.  Be careful not to delete your whole database while using it.  :)

Comment: Note: you can't get a header for TSVs this way, you need something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/57862424

Answer (score 42):

Starting from Bohemian's answer, I found these flags useful:

```
psql my_database -U myuser -A -F , -X -t -f /path/to/query.sql -o /path/to/output.csv
```

- Unaligned output mode: -A
- Use comma as field delimiter: -F ,
- Do not read psqlrc: -X
- Tuples only (no header/footer): -t
- File containing SQL query: -f
- Output file: -o

Comment: This will *not* work as you might expect if you are outputting a text field with a comma in it.

Answer (score 9):

The simplest way (using [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)) seems to be by using `--csv` flag:

```sh
psql --csv -c "SELECT * FROM sometable"
```

Answer (score 8):

EDITED: Using -F

Use commas via `-F` and use "unaligned table output mode" `-A`:

```
psql my_database -U myuser -A -F , -c "select * from mytable"
```

Comment: This will give problems if your separator character appears in values of the column.

Comment: @Red15, how do you go around this problem of ` if your separator character appears in values of the column`

Comment: @Jin You should [ask that as a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @Jin.X I personally think the CSV output (which is the accepted answer) would be the easiest way.

Answer (score 6):

To specify a **tsv** use the delimiter '\t'

```
psql my_database -U myuser -F'\t' --no-align -f mysqlfile.sql -o outputfile.tsv
```

To specify a **csv** use the delimiter ','

```
psql my_database -U myuser -F',' --no-align -f mysqlfile.sql -o outputfile.csv
```

Comment: `'\t'` is not enough in Bash; `--field-separator=$'\t'` works as expected

Answer (score 4):

Also possible is the [copy](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-copy.html) command which allows you to specify header, delimiters and quoting options

```
psql my_database -U my_user -c "copy (select a.id,b.id from my_table_a as a inner join my_table_b as b on b.id = a.id) to STDOUT"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the field separator with the -F command line parameter to psql

Answer (score 2):

**Export AS TSV WITH HEADER**

You can include the HEADER as follows:

```
\COPY (SELECT * FROM tca) TO '/.../metab/tca.tsv' WITH DELIMITER E'\t' CSV HEADER;

\COPY (SELECT * FROM tca) TO '/...a/metab/tca.tsv' WITH NULL AS '' DELIMITER E'\t' CSV HEADER;
```

E.g. (PSQL):

```
[metabolism]# \COPY (SELECT * FROM tca) TO '/mnt/Vancouver/programming/data/metabolism/tca.tsv' WITH NULL AS '' DELIMITER E'\t' CSV HEADER;
COPY 22
```

BASH:

```
[victoria@victoria tsv]$ pwd
/mnt/Vancouver/programming/data/metabolism/tsv

[victoria@victoria tsv]$ head -n3 tca.tsv
uuid    src tgt rel rel_type
878b87de-0ca8-49a8-9f77-a24353e251d2    oxalosuccinic acid  oxoglutaric acid    1.1.1.42    2
7fd9cf88-495b-491b-956e-294f19097923    isocitric acid  oxoglutaric acid    1.1.1.41    2
[victoria@victoria csv]$
```